# Find Maximum and Minimum value by two polynomial equations

Tags: polynomials, systems-of-equations

Suppose there are  $7$ real numbers say $A,B,C,D,E,F,G$ 
All we need to find the minimum and maximum value of $G$ satisfying the following two equations :-

**Sum of Numbers** :- 
$A + B + C + D + E + F + G = 15$

**Sum of Square of Numbers** :-
$A^2 + B^2 + C^2 + D^2 + E^2 + F^2 + G^2 = 33$

I could not figure not how to approach this question !
If possible, somebody provide me the general solution for $N$ number of variables ?

Comment: Your question is not clear. If $A,B,C,D,E,$F and $G$ are given, how do you know that the two equations are satisfied? I think you mean that  $A,B,C,D,E,F,G$ are variables. You should improve your question.

Comment: Updates ! 
Thanks to point out. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint,use Cauchy-Schwarz inequality we have
$$(A^2+B^2+C^2+D^2+E^2+F^2)(1+1+1+1+1+1)\ge (A+B+C+D+E+F)^2$$
then we have
$$6(33-G^2)\ge (15-G)^2$$
then we have to find to $G$ maximum and minimum

so for   the general solution  of $n$ number of variables ?

you can note
$$[a^2_{1}+a^2_{2}+\cdots+a^2_{n-1}][1+1+\cdots+1]\ge [a_{1}+a_{2}+\cdots+a_{n-1}]^2$$

Comment: Thanks sir !!
Now i need to read about Cauchy-Schwarz inequality !! 
It gives a correct answer by my bruteforce program . :)

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

*Sum of numbers:* Set $A= B=\ldots = E=0,F = 15-G$. What values of $G$ can you choose?

*Sum of squared numbers:* Note that $A^2+\ldots +F^2 \geq 0$ and try $A= B=\ldots = E=F=0$. What values of $G$ can you choose?